# Dealing with zero measurments regarding statistical tests

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, t-test

Let say that I have two sets of measurements (two groups of patients A and B, 30 people each). I used some technique that checks particular gene expression. The measurements range from 0 to 100 with an accuracy of two decimal places.

First five example measurements of group A:

```
54.63 43.97 72.35 81.45 94.81 ...
```

Now I'd like to test the hypothesis of difference between means and check whether the gene expression between groups differs.

Unfortunately the second group abounds in 0 measurements (no expression at all). Therefore I see that the expression in first group is higher than i second one. However, after testing, these zeros disrupt the correctness of the test, hence the result is biased and I'm unable to make any conclusions. What can I do in such situation?
Is it correct to add some small value to my measurements? Let's say 0.00001 to deal with these zero measurments?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean that the zeros disrupt the correctness of the test?

Comment: I think that returned p-value is biased due to 'zero' measurments regarding parametric tests.

Comment: How does adding a small value to the zeros help?

Comment: So the 0 values present in dataset have no effect on the test result, now I see thanks!

Comment: Of course your data influence the test result. What, however, do you see being remedied by adding a small value to the zeros?